# yaml to json with Groovy

Tags: json, jenkins, groovy, yaml, jenkins-pipeline

I have a yaml file on a Jenkins pipeline (scripted in Groovy) and I want to convert that yaml file to JSON format to be parsed in that format.

I defined a variable (data) that will contain all the yaml file content. Don't know if that makes it easier to convert or not, but otherwise I can just convert the yaml file without putting the content on a variable.

Groovy stage script:

```
stage ("GET deployConfig file"){
    def data = readYaml file: './evaluations/integration-test- 
    docker/dev/deployConfig.yaml'
    println("YAML-FILE: " + data)     
}
```

Does anyone know how can achieve that?

thanks

Comment: I hope you realize that only a miniscule fraction of YAML files can actually be represented as JSON (even when restricting the input YAML files not to use tags or anchors/aliases))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert to json and write it to file

```
import groovy.json.*

stage{
    def data = readYaml file: ....
    def json = new JsonBuilder(data).toPrettyString()
    writeFile file: ..., text: json
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone finds this useful.

Using new JsonBuilder resulted in Jenkins (via a groovy script) throwing an exception; used `JsonOutput.toJson(data)` instead.

```
def json = JsonOutput.toJson(data)
```